# Attemption to create thread safe std::map

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Suppose that we have `std::map` container and we want to make it thread safe in terms of insert, erase, search and edit records. At the same time we want the threads can work with different records in parallel (read and edit records). To do this, I made a separate class for record - edit operation, which protected with mutex.

```
class Data
{
public:
    Data(const std::string& data) : _mutex(), _data(data) { }
    void setData(const std::string& data)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_mutex);
        _data = data;
    }

    const std::string& getData() const { return _data; }

private:
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::string _data;
};

class Storage
{
public:
    void insertData(size_t key, const std::string& data)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_mutex);
        _storage[key] = data;
    }

    void eraseData(size_t key)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_mutex);
        _storage.erase(key);
    }

    const std::string& getData(size_t key) const { return _storage[key].getData(); }

    void setData(size_t key, const std::string& data) { _storage[key].setData(data); }

private:
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::map<size_t, Data> _storage;
};
```

Now suppose that the thread grabbs "local" mutex of the some record to edit (`Data::setData` method call). In the same time, other thread  grabbs "global" mutex to delete this record (`Storage::eraseData` method call) - are there any problems? What other problems are possible in this code?

Comment: Tree data structures are not friendly to multithreading at all.

Comment: I would also check out TBB's [threadsafe map](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm) implementation as part of the threadsafe containers library.

Comment: @PetrPervukhin: They can be. Especially if they are designed to lock nodes individually and be a bit sloppy and not balance on every single update. Because if threads are operating on independent tree nodes, they aren't interfering with each other.

Comment: @ZanLynx: you are right. But i still fill that skip list will be better if there is many insertion/deletions. However i have no tested them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve your concurrency problems first.  This is a C++14 solution, because the C++11 version is much more verbose, and we don't have all the locking primitives we want:

```
template<class T>
struct thread_safe {
  template<class F>
  auto read( F&& f ) const {
    std::shared_lock<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
    return std::forward<F>(f)(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write( F&& f ) {
    std::unique_lock<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
    return std::forward<F>(f)(t);
  }
  template<class O>
  thread_safe(O&&o):t(std::forward<O>(o)) {}

  thread_safe() = default;

  operator T() const {
    return o.read([](T const& t){return t;});
  }

  // it is really this simple:
  thread_safe( thread_safe const& o ):t( o ) {}

  // forward to above thread safe copy ctor:
  thread_safe( thread_safe & o ):thread_safe( const_cast<thread_safe const&>(o) ) {}
  thread_safe( thread_safe && o ):thread_safe(o) {}
  thread_safe( thread_safe const&& o ):thread_safe(o) {}

  thead_safe& operator=( thread_safe const& o ) {
    write( [&o](auto& target) {
      target = o;
    });
    return *this;
  } 
  template<class O>
  thread_safe& operator=( O&& o ) {
    write([&o](auto& t){ t = std::forward<O>(o); });
    return *this;
  }
private:
  T t;
  mutable std::shared_timed_mutex mutex;
};
```

this is a thread safety wrapper around an arbitrary class.

We can use this directly:

```
typedef thread_safe< std::map< size_t, thread_safe<std::string> > > my_map;
```

here we have our two level thread safe map.

Example use, setting entry 33 to `"hello"`:

```
my_map.write( [&](auto&& m){
  m[33] = "hello";
} );
```

this has many-readers, single-writer on each element and on the map as a whole.  Returning an iterator from a `read` or `write` call is not safe.

Naturally you should test and audit the above code.  I didn't.

The core idea is pretty simple.  To read, you have to `.read` the thread safe object.  The lambda you pass in gets a `const&` to the underlying data.  On `std::` data, those are guaranteed to be multi-reader safe.

To write, you must `.write`.  This gets an exclusive lock, blocking out other `.read`s.  The lambda here gets a `&` to the underlying data.

I added `operator T` and `=` and copy-construct to make the type more regular.  The cost of this is that you can accidentally generate a lot of lock/unlock behavior.  The advantage is that `m[33] = "hello"` **just works**, which is awesome.

Comment: @gorill As noted by a friend, the inner `thread_safe<std::string>` is mostly redundant, as in order to get at the non-const `std::string` you need to have a non-`const` access to the `map`, which means you already have a unique lock.  If you make it `std::unique_ptr<thread_safe<std::string>>` that is no longer true.

Comment: @gorill The core problem is that some non-`const` methods to containers are thread-safe-`const` (ie, read operations, even though they are non-`const`), like `begin()`, `end()`, `find()`.  I am not sure the best way to handle that problem.  Hmm.

Comment: @ Yakk, best way is fully reimplement rb-tree in the threadsafe manner))))

Answer (score 1):

You have two huge problems:

1. What happens if one thread calls `insertData` at the same time another thread calls `getData`? The call to `operator[]` can crash because the map is being modified while it's trying to access it.
2. What happens if one thread calls `eraseData` while another thread is still using the reference it got back from `getData`? The reference could become invalid, causing a crash.