# C++ thread-safe bracket operator proxy

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Given a simple wrapper around a standard vector, what is a good way to implement `operator[]` in a thread-safe way in order to be able to set the content as usual?

```
struct bracket_operator_proxy;

struct example
{
    auto operator[](size_t i) const { return bracket_operator_proxy(v, m, i); }
private:
    std::vector<double> v;
    std::mutex m;
};
```

Here is my quick and naive attempt for `bracket_operator_proxy`:

```
struct bracket_operator_proxy
{
     bracket_operator_proxy(std::vector<double>& v, std::mutex& m, int i)
        : v(v), m(m), i(i) {}

     operator double() const
     {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
         return v[i];
     }

     auto operator=(double d)
     {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
         v[i] = d;
         return d;
     }

     //... further assignment operators ...
private:
     std::vector<double>& v;
     std::mutex& m;
     int i;
};
```

Is this already enough? Or am I missing something which will blow my leg off?

Comment: You currently forbid `(example[i] = 4.2) = 42;` as your `operator =` return `double` and not `bracket_operator_proxy&`. Not a pitfall.

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, that was intention. Otherwise, I think, I'd have to unlock the mutex in the destructor. Any ideas for a better alternative?

Comment: The mutex is unlocked at the end of `operator=`, so returning `bracket_operator_proxy&` should be ok. BTW `std::vector<std::atomic<double>>` seems a good alternative.

Comment: I don't see any pitfall in your code

Comment: Like @Jarod42, I'd also use std::vector<std::atomic<double>>. Allows concurrent work when not affecting the same vector element, much less coding (and less opportunity for error).

Comment: I'm not convinced this will be safe to use in general.  For example, what if another thread clears the underlying vector just before immediately before you set/get a value in the vector?  Then you'd be getting/setting an invalid index, and the fact that you were doing so while the mutex is locked wouldn't prevent undefined behavior and/or an assertion failure.  I think the locking needs to be done at a higher level than this, unless you can give guarantees e.g. that the vector's length won't ever change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `operator->` (which is very useful) you'll need to return a `->` proxy which extends lock lifetime until end of statement, and exposes you to single threaded deadlock.

Look at thread safe monads/functor/wrapper like [the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26391895/1774667).  It doesn't make the locks completely transparent, but *they should not be*.

- Do not share data between threads
- If you share data, make it immutable
- If it must be mutated, isolate access through a bottleneck of known safe design.  A message queue say.
- If you cannot do that, consider redesign
- Really.  Atomic maybe?
- Have a limited set of functions that manage locks explicitly
- Ok, now wrap in reader/writer monad as above, with easy-ish compound operations
- Make code that magically gets locks and looks just like non-thread interacting code, thus lulling your readers into a false sense of security and efficiency

In decreasing preference.

The dangerous and hard part of thread safety is not the fact that the syntax is awkward.  It is that lock based thread safety is nearly impossible to prove correct and safe.  Making the syntax easier to use is not a high value goal.

As an example, `v[i]=v[i+1]` is fraught with a lack of synchronization: between the read and the write anything could have changed.  Let alone the problem of "is `i` a valid index?"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the link to the thread-safe wrapper and the example where it can go wrong. Somehow it seems to me as if multithreading had to be ugly...

Comment: Given I provide use pointers instead of references and provide a reasonable [copy constructor](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-safe-copy-constructors.html) and class-assignment operator, does it become thread-safe? (I know you said it's nearly impossible to prove, so please follow your intuition). The problem is I have already used `operator[]`in various locations in my lib, and further encourage users to extend the functionality -- which imo should then be as easy as possible.

Comment: @davidhigh Single threaded code, and multi-threaded code where you are aquiring and releasing locks at various spots while other threads modify things, are *fundamentally different beasts*.  As simple as `a[i] = a[i-1]+1` has completely different meaning in multi threaded code as single threaded code (the single-threaded post condition is that `a[i]` is one bigger than `a[i-1]`, but that is *not true* in multi-threaded code).  Making existing code compile is a horrible way to write multi-threaded code.  And if you have more than 1 lock, or non-reentrant locks, it will almost always lock up.